# Why can I not get quotation marks converted to guillemets?

Tags: quotation

I used some of the great advice on this site to try to change my quotation marks (source file: markdown) into guillemets. Unfortunately it does not work, they end up as plain `"` in the pdf output. On top of that, in some cases there seems to be a misinterpretation of my source `"`which ends up being turned into German Umlauts (at least that is what I suppose is happening). Clearly I am doint something wrong in these files:
.tex

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{Weidefleisch}
\author{My Name}
\date{September 2021}
\usepackage{markdown}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202F}{\,}
\begin{document}
\markdownInput{test.md}
\end{document}
```

.md:

```
Ich bekomme weder "diese", noch "diese" Anführungszeichen in Guillemets umgewandelt.
Meine Zitate funktionieren auch nicht richtig.[^Siehe dieses Klammer]
Auch dieses Zitatformat löst das Problem nicht.^[Andere Reihenfolge]
Sonderzeichen grad: 15°C
```

Could you help me?

(I end up with this:

```
Ich bekomme weder "diese", noch "dieseÄnführungszeichen in Guillemets
umgewandelt. Meine Zitate funktionieren auch nicht richtig.[^Siehe dieses Klam-
mer] Auch dieses Zitatformat löst das Problem nicht.^[Andere Reihenfolge] Son-
derzeichen grad: 15°C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add `\MakeOuterQuote{"}`. The examples I checked and added links to in the comments stated to instead use `\MakeAutoQuote{"}`. That is what I tried before. It did not work and produced error messages.

So, to automatically convert `"` into `»` and `«`, use this:

```
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
```